# 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found using cocoapod and use_frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have installed the `Facebook SDK` using `cocoapods` in my `objective-c` project.  This is how I added it in the pod file

```
use_frameworks!
  pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

The problem is that the build failed because of that: `'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found`. I searched about that and I found that if the  `use_frameworks!` is added in the pod file, then the  `pod "Bolts";` must be added before the   `pod "FBSDKCoreKit";` (from the facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced)). This is what I did but it doesn’t work. I tried also to clean the project, and use this command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` but also without any result.
Can anyone please tell me where is he problem with what I did?

**Edit**

When I remove the `use_frameworks!`
this is what I get in the error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts' 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove YourPod file Because you are using "" and semi colons and add these pod files It will work

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
```

These Frame work import

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Appdelegate.m

```
  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
  {                      

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  }

 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url**strong text** sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
  {

      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I correct it in my podfile and in my answer too but I still having the same problem

Comment: Should I add anything in the build setting search path?

Comment: If you are using Pod file than no need search path If you download sdk than drag and drop sdk in your project  for more info check doc  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

Comment: No I want to use the pod file. Have you any other ideas to resolve this problem please?

Comment: Add these pod file and #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h> these header file

Comment: I tried what you said but the build failed for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but I have already done those thinks but without result. Thank you again!